# Find Lipschtiz constant for a function in matrix

Tags: matrices, analysis, lipschitz-functions

I have the following function in $X \in R^{n \times k}$

$$f(X) = -4A X\Lambda_1 + 4(X\Lambda_1 X^T X\Lambda_1) - 4A^TXY\Lambda_2Y^T + 4XY\Lambda_2Y^TX^TXY\Lambda_2Y^T$$

where $A \in R^{n \times n}$, $Y \in R^{k \times k1}$, $\Lambda_1 \in R^{k \times k}$ and $\Lambda_2 \in R^{k1 \times k1}$, and $\Lambda_1 , \Lambda_2$ are diagonal matrices. How can I find Lipschitz constant of the above function with respect to frobenious norm? Would it be possible to find local Lipschitz constant I know ||X||? The f function is gradient with respect to X and I am trying to do a gradient descent, so, I will have bounds on ||X||.

Comment: There is no global Lipschitz constant for $f$.

Comment: @copper.hat Why is there no global Lipschitz?

Comment: Well, it depends on the actual values of the matrices above, but consider the formula for scalars, there is an $X^3$ term which is not Lipschitz.

Comment: @copper.hat What if I know ||X||? The $f$ function is gradient with respect to $X$ and I am trying to do a gradient descent, so, I will have bounds on ||X||.

Comment: I don't know what to say. In general, the function is not globally Lipschitz. On any bounded set you can find a local Lipschitz constant. One way is to find the derivative of $f$ with respect to $X$ and bound the derivative.

Comment: @copper.hat It would be very complicated to find the derivate. Would it be possible to find local Lipschitz constant without derivate if I have bounds on norms of ||X||?

Comment: It is not that complicated.